# Как создать папку программы в /sdcard/Android/data и выгрузить нужные данные для работы приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужно создать папку в /sdcard/Android/data,которая доступна для чтения и записи.
Многие программы так делают и выгружают туда свои данные для работы.
Мне нужно,чтобы при первом запуске программы создалась папка и туда выгрузились нужный файлы из /res/raw
Каким способом можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В onCreate:

```
BootloaderCopyFileInWorkDirectory(R.raw.locked);
```

---

Далее:

```
 private void BootloaderCopyFileInWorkDirectory(int Resource){
        String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                "/Android/data/com.path.something/files/Bootloader/locked"; // File path
        try{
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(Resource);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Обязательно указываем в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```